# Anthology story of a vampire warded off by the protagonist's faith in money

Tags: story-identification

In the late 1980s or very early 1990s, I read a story in what I recall was an anthology of vampire stories.

In the story, a man is being attacked by a vampire, and at the last moment, when all hope is lost, throws money at the vampire. The vamp is warded off as if by a cross, and the near-victim is saved **due to his true faith in money.**

Answer (score 8):

This is "[Money Talks](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/503613.Ghosts)" by Dick Baldwin (from 1980).

> A delicious, sly swipe at status-symbol-loving yuppies fused with a
> good solid (yet compact) vampire story, “Money Talks” is perhaps the
> best example I have yet found of vampire mythology in which **the
> effectiveness of weapons against the vampire lies not in their
> religious symbolism but in the faith of the person wielding them.**
> Suspenseful, with a wonderfully repellent vampire, and a brilliant
> ending. This definitely deserves to be more widely known. Find it in
> Ghosts: A Treasury of Chilling Tales Old and New, edited by Marvin
> Kaye and Saralee Kaye.
>
> <sub><sup>[Halloween Vampire Anthology review](http://www.amandadewees.com/halloween-vampire-anthology/)</sup></sub>

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I can't tell you how many times I've thought of this story over the years, without having been able to track it down.  This is it!!!

Comment: Great to hear it. Don't forget to upvote and click the "accepted" button.